# Installing Vending & gms apk files

Tags: android, google-api, emulation

### I Installed `vending` and `gms apk` files using adb command

---

[image]

**I am doing this to run my Map API in my android emulator**

Now if i run my android program .... i get the message as,

[image]

- How to resolve this so that i can successfully run my program!
- How to update the google maps as shown in my emulator

Comment: Me too installed both apk's on simulator, but still me also having same problem.

Comment: Have you checked these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865783/google-maps-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services ?

Comment: Yes, i have checked those links .... through those i found out how to install apk's ....... but how to update the google play services .... any command for that ?

Comment: @smriti2 Check out the blog http://blogprogramistyandroid.blogspot.in/2013/08/creating-android-emulator-v17-that.html which have provided a solution for this. I hope it will guide you.